# Do svn import or add+commit in Jenkins?

Tags: svn, jenkins

I would like to make Jenkins add its build artifacts - in my case test results - to a svn repo.
I need to add+commit or import the new created results files - unversioned files - into a svn repo. This ResultsFolder does also contains older files from older test runs which are versioned. 
The repo was checked out by Jenkins first.

Is this the way to do it?

1. Add build step in Jenkins, Execute Windows Batch cmd (Jenkins runs on a Windows machine)
2. Svn add cmd: `svn add .\ResultsFolder\*` to add all files of folder "ResultsFolder" recursively. The folder contains also versioned files and folders, is this a problem?!
3. Svn commit cmd: `svn ci .` to commit previous add to the repo.

The reason why I do this is because the test results need to be:

1. Backuped
2. Checked out on another machine for further analysis

Comment: Maybe a little more context about the environment. The project exists out multiple platforms: .NET, Qt, embedded linux...

Comment: The tests are situated at system level. And I made a dedicated test sequencer which can interact with the system. The test system engine is in .NET. I use my own test sequence script (serialized xml) and my test results are also saved in this format. As test management system I use [TestLink](http://www.teamst.org/). In order to automate some tests, I use the Jenkins [TestLink plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/TestLink+Plugin). This will get the tests from and report back to TestLink. To interface with the plugin my test system outputs in TestNG pattern format.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a problem: Whenever you have Jenkins check in a new Subversion revision, it'll fire off another Jenkins build. You probably don't want that. Plus, you shouldn't check into Subversion something that is generated by the build. It'll quickly cause your repository to grow beyond your current disk size, and you'll end up with a ton of artifacts in your repository no one is interested in. Instead:

#### Use the archive abilities of Jenkins to save your build artifacts.

This makes them much more visible and easier to find. Plus, you can automatically have Jenkins get rid of them when you're no longer interested in them. Remember you can *lock* a Jenkins build in order to prevent artifacts you do want to keep (such as an actual release binary) much easier to find.

Plus, your other machine can use `wget` or `curl` to pull them off the Jenkins repository.

#### Use the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) for your other job.

If the another Jenkins job that requires these artifacts is another Jenkins job, you can use this plugin to copy the artifacts from this job into the other job, and automatically execute the second job. I do this when I have tests to run against a build that might take more than a few minutes to run.

#### Go All Out and Use Maven

Even if you're not using Maven as a build process, it's a great way to store and manage artifacts. Jenkins can store artifacts in Maven as part of the build process, and you can use `wget`, `curl`, or even Maven itself to automatically fetch the artifacts from the repository.

This is a bit more complex, but it's a defined standard method that's independent of Jenkins. This is nice if you decide to move from Jenkins to say TeamCity. You're not stuck depending upon a proprietary process in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you look at using [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) instead of reinventing it?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did for my POM file:

```
rem
rem Update SVN with pom.xml file with bumped version
rem
svn co "SVN PATH" %WORKSPACE%\temp --depth files
cd %WORKSPACE%\temp
cp ../pom.xml .
svn ci pom.xml -m "Jenkins : Version Bump"
rd /s /q %WORKSPACE%\temp
```